# How to remove List parent node from xml?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I Have tried to remove scheme-details1 from Below XML using the below code but unable to remove it.

```
XmlActionResult xmlActionResult = new XmlActionResult(schememaster);
foreach (XElement element in xmlActionResult._document.Elements()) 
{ 
    xmlActionResult._document.Elements("scheme-details1").Remove(); 
}
```

where `xmlActionResult._document` is `XDocument`.

Below is my XML response:-

```
<scheme-master>
    <general-information>
        <schemecode>XXXXX</schemecode>
        <year>2020</year>
        <month>04</month>
        <requestid>0008052020</requestid>
    </general-information>
    <scheme-details1>
        <scheme-details>
            <location>
                <district_code>503</district_code>
                <district_name>Chittoor</district_name>
                <state_code>28</state_code>
                <state_name>Andhra pradesh</state_name>
            </location>
            <beneficiary-details>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_normative_central_and_state_share>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_normative_central_and_state_share>
                <no_of_additional_beneficiaries_supported_by_state>0</no_of_additional_beneficiaries_supported_by_state>
                <total_no_of_beneficiaries>10000</total_no_of_beneficiaries>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_record_digitized>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_record_digitized>
                <no_of_authenticated_seeded_beneficiaries>10000</no_of_authenticated_seeded_beneficiaries>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_whom_mobile_no_captured>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_whom_mobile_no_captured>
            </beneficiary-details>
            <fundtransfer-details>
                <central_share_fund_transferred_cash>10000</central_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <normative_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>0</normative_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <additional_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>0</additional_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <state_share_fund_transferred_to_additional_beneficiaries_cash>0</state_share_fund_transferred_to_additional_beneficiaries_cash>
                <total_fund_transferred_cash>10000</total_fund_transferred_cash>
                <central_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</central_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <normative_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</normative_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <additional_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</additional_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <state_share_expenditure_incurred_to_additional_beneficiaries_inkind>0</state_share_expenditure_incurred_to_additional_beneficiaries_inkind>
                <total_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</total_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
            </fundtransfer-details>
            <transaction-details>
                <total_no_transactions_electronic_modes_cash>10000</total_no_transactions_electronic_modes_cash>
                <payment_electronic_modes_cash>10000</payment_electronic_modes_cash>
                <total_no_transactions_other_modes_cash>0</total_no_transactions_other_modes_cash>
                <payment_other_modes_cash>0</payment_other_modes_cash>
                <quantity_transferred_inkind>0</quantity_transferred_inkind>
                <no_of_authenticated_transactions_inkind>0</no_of_authenticated_transactions_inkind>
                <dbt_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</dbt_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
            </transaction-details>
        </scheme-details>
        <scheme-details>
            <location>
                <district_code>504</district_code>
                <district_name>Cuddapah (YSR Kadapa)</district_name>
                <state_code>28</state_code>
                <state_name>Andhra pradesh</state_name>
            </location>
            <beneficiary-details>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_normative_central_and_state_share>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_normative_central_and_state_share>
                <no_of_additional_beneficiaries_supported_by_state>0</no_of_additional_beneficiaries_supported_by_state>
                <total_no_of_beneficiaries>10000</total_no_of_beneficiaries>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_record_digitized>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_record_digitized>
                <no_of_authenticated_seeded_beneficiaries>10000</no_of_authenticated_seeded_beneficiaries>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_whom_mobile_no_captured>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_whom_mobile_no_captured>
            </beneficiary-details>
            <fundtransfer-details>
                <central_share_fund_transferred_cash>10000</central_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <normative_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>0</normative_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <additional_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>0</additional_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <state_share_fund_transferred_to_additional_beneficiaries_cash>0</state_share_fund_transferred_to_additional_beneficiaries_cash>
                <total_fund_transferred_cash>10000</total_fund_transferred_cash>
                <central_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</central_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <normative_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</normative_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <additional_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</additional_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <state_share_expenditure_incurred_to_additional_beneficiaries_inkind>0</state_share_expenditure_incurred_to_additional_beneficiaries_inkind>
                <total_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</total_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
            </fundtransfer-details>
            <transaction-details>
                <total_no_transactions_electronic_modes_cash>10000</total_no_transactions_electronic_modes_cash>
                <payment_electronic_modes_cash>10000</payment_electronic_modes_cash>
                <total_no_transactions_other_modes_cash>0</total_no_transactions_other_modes_cash>
                <payment_other_modes_cash>0</payment_other_modes_cash>
                <quantity_transferred_inkind>0</quantity_transferred_inkind>
                <no_of_authenticated_transactions_inkind>0</no_of_authenticated_transactions_inkind>
                <dbt_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</dbt_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
            </transaction-details>
        </scheme-details>
        <scheme-details>
            <location>
                <district_code>503</district_code>
                <district_name>Chittoor</district_name>
                <state_code>28</state_code>
                <state_name>Andhra pradesh</state_name>
            </location>
            <beneficiary-details>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_normative_central_and_state_share>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_normative_central_and_state_share>
                <no_of_additional_beneficiaries_supported_by_state>0</no_of_additional_beneficiaries_supported_by_state>
                <total_no_of_beneficiaries>10000</total_no_of_beneficiaries>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_record_digitized>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_record_digitized>
                <no_of_authenticated_seeded_beneficiaries>10000</no_of_authenticated_seeded_beneficiaries>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_whom_mobile_no_captured>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_whom_mobile_no_captured>
            </beneficiary-details>
            <fundtransfer-details>
                <central_share_fund_transferred_cash>10000</central_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <normative_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>0</normative_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <additional_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>0</additional_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <state_share_fund_transferred_to_additional_beneficiaries_cash>0</state_share_fund_transferred_to_additional_beneficiaries_cash>
                <total_fund_transferred_cash>10000</total_fund_transferred_cash>
                <central_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</central_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <normative_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</normative_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <additional_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</additional_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <state_share_expenditure_incurred_to_additional_beneficiaries_inkind>0</state_share_expenditure_incurred_to_additional_beneficiaries_inkind>
                <total_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</total_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
            </fundtransfer-details>
            <transaction-details>
                <total_no_transactions_electronic_modes_cash>10000</total_no_transactions_electronic_modes_cash>
                <payment_electronic_modes_cash>10000</payment_electronic_modes_cash>
                <total_no_transactions_other_modes_cash>0</total_no_transactions_other_modes_cash>
                <payment_other_modes_cash>0</payment_other_modes_cash>
                <quantity_transferred_inkind>0</quantity_transferred_inkind>
                <no_of_authenticated_transactions_inkind>0</no_of_authenticated_transactions_inkind>
                <dbt_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</dbt_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
            </transaction-details>
        </scheme-details>
        <scheme-details>
            <location>
                <district_code>504</district_code>
                <district_name>Cuddapah (YSR Kadapa)</district_name>
                <state_code>28</state_code>
                <state_name>Andhra pradesh</state_name>
            </location>
            <beneficiary-details>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_normative_central_and_state_share>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_normative_central_and_state_share>
                <no_of_additional_beneficiaries_supported_by_state>0</no_of_additional_beneficiaries_supported_by_state>
                <total_no_of_beneficiaries>10000</total_no_of_beneficiaries>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_record_digitized>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_record_digitized>
                <no_of_authenticated_seeded_beneficiaries>10000</no_of_authenticated_seeded_beneficiaries>
                <no_of_beneficiaries_whom_mobile_no_captured>10000</no_of_beneficiaries_whom_mobile_no_captured>
            </beneficiary-details>
            <fundtransfer-details>
                <central_share_fund_transferred_cash>10000</central_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <normative_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>0</normative_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <additional_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>0</additional_state_share_fund_transferred_cash>
                <state_share_fund_transferred_to_additional_beneficiaries_cash>0</state_share_fund_transferred_to_additional_beneficiaries_cash>
                <total_fund_transferred_cash>10000</total_fund_transferred_cash>
                <central_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</central_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <normative_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</normative_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <additional_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</additional_state_share_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
                <state_share_expenditure_incurred_to_additional_beneficiaries_inkind>0</state_share_expenditure_incurred_to_additional_beneficiaries_inkind>
                <total_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</total_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
            </fundtransfer-details>
            <transaction-details>
                <total_no_transactions_electronic_modes_cash>10000</total_no_transactions_electronic_modes_cash>
                <payment_electronic_modes_cash>10000</payment_electronic_modes_cash>
                <total_no_transactions_other_modes_cash>0</total_no_transactions_other_modes_cash>
                <payment_other_modes_cash>0</payment_other_modes_cash>
                <quantity_transferred_inkind>0</quantity_transferred_inkind>
                <no_of_authenticated_transactions_inkind>0</no_of_authenticated_transactions_inkind>
                <dbt_expenditure_incurred_inkind>0</dbt_expenditure_incurred_inkind>
            </transaction-details>
        </scheme-details>
    </scheme-details1>
</scheme-master>
```

Comment: Please update your question, and add a desired output XML.

Comment: In the loop you need to do `element.Elements("scheme-details1").Remove();`.  Or eliminate the loop and do `xmlActionResult._document.Root.Elements("scheme-details1").Remove();`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/0vZMoK

Comment: When ever you have a list you have to start at end and move towards beginning : List<XElement> elements = xmlActionResult._document.Elements().ToList();
for (int i = elements.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
     elements[i].Remove;
}

Comment: In your question you defined a variable `xmlActionResult1` but then tried to remove nodes from the document of `xmlActionResult`.  Assuming this was a typo in the question, I edited the variable names to be consistent.  If you really have two different `XmlActionResult` objects in your code that could also explain your problem -- you might be removing nodes from the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through the `XElement element` root node(s) of your `XDocument` but then try to remove the `<scheme-details1>` nodes from the document itself.  Instead, remove them from the current `element`:

```
foreach (var element in xmlActionResult._document.Elements()) 
{ 
    //xmlActionResult._document.Elements("scheme-details1").Remove(); // FIXED
    element.Elements("scheme-details1").Remove();               
}
```

Or, since a well-formed XML document always has exactly one [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), you could eliminate the loop through the root elements and just do:

```
xmlActionResult._document.Root.Elements("scheme-details1").Remove();
```

Demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0vZMoK).

**Update**

[`Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.extensions.remove?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Linq_Extensions_Remove__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) removes a collection of nodes *and all their descendants* from their parent(s).  If you want to remove the `<scheme-details1>` node and bubble all its children up to its parent node, you can create the following extension methods:

```
public static class XNodeExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveAndMoveChildrenUp (this IEnumerable<XNode> source)
    {
        foreach (var node in source.ToList())
            node.RemoveAndMoveChildrenOfTypeUp<XNode>();
    }
    
    public static void RemoveAndMoveChildElementsUp (this IEnumerable<XNode> source)
    {
        foreach (var node in source.ToList())
            node.RemoveAndMoveChildrenOfTypeUp<XElement>();
    }
    
    public static void RemoveAndMoveChildrenOfTypeUp<TChild>(this XNode node) where TChild : XNode
    {
        var parent = node.Parent;
        if (node is XContainer container)
        {
            for (XNode child = container.FirstNode, nextChild = child?.NextNode; child != null; child = nextChild, nextChild = child?.NextNode)
            {
                if (child is TChild)
                {
                    child.Remove(); // Remove the child first to prevent cloning when added to the parent
                    parent.Add(child);
                }
            }
        }
        node.Remove();
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
xmlActionResult._document.Root.Elements("scheme-details1").RemoveAndMoveChildrenUp();
```

Or, if `<scheme-details1>` were a [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content) node and you wanted to bubble up only the child *elements*, use `RemoveAndMoveChildElementsUp()`.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pA9Obz).

Comment: Have Tried with the same as well and it will return Void. I got a solution by doing this, I have just replace that tag with empty.                                                                             
           string xml = doc.ToString();
            xml = xml.Replace("<scheme-details1>", "");
            xml = xml.Replace("</scheme-details1>", "");
            doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

Comment: In Your above answer, it is correct to remove scheme-details1, But it remove that whole completely, I just want to remove that TAG from XML not the entire Scheme-Details1 block.

Answer (score 0):

The above-posted answer also works and the one has got with also works for me by replacing the tag from XML.

```
            XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            {
                // write xml into the writer
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
                serializer.WriteObject(writer, obj);
            }
            string xml = doc.ToString();
            xml = xml.Replace("<scheme-details1>", "");
            xml = xml.Replace("</scheme-details1>", "");
            doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```